# Traverse Realm Query into RealmList

Tags: java, realm

I have a Realm object called "Mix" which contains a field that is a RealmList called user_tags. These tag objects are also Realm objects and have a field called "type". I'd like to query Realm for all Mix objects that have a UserTag with a certain type. Is this possible?

Eg:

Mix.java

```
public class Mix extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    private RealmList<UserTag> user_tags = new RealmList<>();
}
```

Usertag.java

```
public class UserTag extends RealmObject {

    private String tag_type;
}
```

**TLDR**: How can I query realm to get Mix objects that contain a UserTag that has a particular tag_type?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible.

```
realm.where(Mix.class).equalTo("user_tags.tag_type", "xxx").findAll()
```

See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries for more information.